# Two diffenrent shapes in render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a newbie in blender, i solved a lot of problems thanks to this forum but this time i can't find any answer to my problem.

So basically i downloaded a 3D model, put some textures on it, etc.. but when i do the render the 3D model appears 2 times (no matter what type of render i use).

[image]

[image]

I don't realy know what to do, so if someone know i would be pleased to know what is the solution !

Thanks in advance and have a great day !

Comment: I don't see the image clearly, but perhaps you have an extra car hidden? Try using Alt+H to show everything.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have a second model just hidden, you need to disable it in the render too.

To do so press the camera icon that I marked in the image.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help !